# Trying to Understand Erdős–Wintner Theorem

Tags: number-theory, probability-distributions

I would like to use the [Erdős–Wintner theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Wintner_theorem), but not quite sure if I can. I have a function $f$ that I believe is additive and in the process of proving/disproving, but $f(p) \nleq 1$ for all $p$. Does this mean that if I just show the first series (leftmost in link) converges I have a limiting distribution? Or does it mean that I can't use the theorem? I no longer have access to the original paper anymore since taking off from school, but when I did I was still not sure.